# Cannot access apache form outside network

Tags: networking, ssh, apache2, dns, firewall

I cannot access apache from outsid the network. From "inside", it works.
In the Firewall "Apache Full" is enabled.

```
 sudo iptables -vL
```

Returns this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 4 packets, 144 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
97952   92M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
97952   92M ufw-before-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
74296   82M ufw-after-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
73241   82M ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
73241   82M ufw-reject-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
73241   82M ufw-track-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
87143   31M ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
87143   31M ufw-before-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
58731   14M ufw-after-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
58731   14M ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
58731   14M ufw-reject-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
58731   14M ufw-track-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6   468 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
    1   229 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
  630  118K ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    5   180 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  186 14833 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
 7858  570K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
  642  119K ufw-not-local  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
  642  119K ufw-user-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  186 14833 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            
 9872 6801K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    60 ufw-user-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    5   180 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
  637  119K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  637  119K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https /* 'dapp_Apache%20Full' */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I have a dynamic IP, so, I use a dns service.
That works, because I can ream my cam, which is connected to the same network.
In my Router, I opened port 80 and port 8080.
I also disabled ufw, without success....
What could be the issue?
Are there any tools, I can run, to get more info, about the problem?
Openssh also doesn't work, when I try to access it from outside.

Many Thanks,
Lars

Comment: Did you forward the ports in the router to the machine running apache?

Comment: yes. I did.80 and 8080 and assigned it to the machine....